# How to solve this sequence problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

$a_1, a_2, a_3\dots\;$ are numbers in a sequence with the condition
$$a_{n+1}= a_n + ka_n$$
where k is a constant.
If the first number is $20,$ the last is $20000$
 and total numbers are $1400.$    Find $k.$

Comment: This is the same as $a_{n+1} = (k+1)a_n$ which is an exponential function.

Comment: It appears that you are saying $a_{n+1}=(1+k)a_n$, no?  So then the final sum is essentially a (finite) geometric series.

Comment: Yes @lulu But what we do next?

Comment: To get $k$ note that  $\frac {a_{1400}}{a_1}=\frac {20000}{20}$

Comment: @lulu okay. But I m doing this for music theory. And i cannot dig into sequence and series right now. My basics aren't good in that topic. Would you please find k for me?

Comment: What do you call "total numbers" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is, as others said, a geometric sequence with common ratio 1+ k. $a_n= a_1(1+ k)^{n-1}$ and the sum, to k= n, is $a_1\frac{1- (1+ k)^n}{k}$.
"The first number is 20".  So $a_1= 20$.
"The last number is 20000". So $a_n= 20(1+ k)^{n-1}= 20000$.  $(1+ k)^{n-1}= 1000$.
"The sum is 14000".  That's impossible.  The sum is 20000 plus other positive numbers so must be larger than 20000.  I am going to try "The last number is 2000" rather than 20000.  Then we have $(1+ k)^{n-1}= 100$ and $20\frac{1- (1+ k)^n}{k}= 1400$ or $\frac{1- (1+ k)^n}{k}= 70$.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is $a_1=20$, the last number is $a_{1400}=20000$. The definition tells you that
$$
a_{1400}=20(1+k)^{1399}
$$
so
$$
(1+k)^{1399}=1000
$$
and therefore
$$
k=\sqrt[1399]{1000}-1\approx0.00494984801948955147
$$